# An error occurred while rendering Pivot.jsp while try to view the published cube

Tags: pentaho, mondrian, pentaho-cde, pentaho-ctools

I am using pentaho community versions for "biserver-ce-5.2.0.0-209" for bi server for viewing the published cube and  "psw-ce-3.9.0.0-213" for schema workbench for  creation of a sample cube which i published successfully

But when i am trying to do Jpivot_view for the cube that i published i am getting the below error

**An error occurred while rendering Pivot.jsp. Please see the log for details**

Can anyone help me on this

Comment: It means that there is something wrong in your schema like referencing a non existing table or column. The fact that your schema is correctly published just indicates that it is syntaxically correct

Comment: Hi the problem has been resolved we need to define the connection jdbc in the user console "Manage Data Sources" and then can view the analytics report